# How to remove focus from button after closing the "altertify" confirm modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alertifyjs

I have a button with `:hover` and `:focus` css property. While hovering on it the color changes to red.
Now when i click on it a Alertify confirm box appears and then i press ok or cancel the color changes to red again because of `:focus` property.
How can i unbind `:focus` when clicked on ok or cancel.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.8.0/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.8.0/css/alertify.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.8.0/css/themes/default.min.css"/>

</head>

<style>
.btn-test:hover,.btn-test:focus{
background-color:red;
}
</style>

<body>


<button class="btn-test">Click Me</button>


</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(".btn-test").click(function(){

 alertify.confirm('Confirmation', 'You clicked', function () {
                //do nothing
            }
            , function () {
                //do nothing
            });

});
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to just add this code in js file  $(".btn-test").blur(); like this:

```js
$(".btn-test").click(function(){

        $(".btn-test").blur();        
   

 alertify.confirm('Confirmation', 'You clicked', function () {
                //do nothing
            }
            , function () {
                //do nothing
            });

});
```

```css
.btn-test:hover,.btn-test:focus{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.8.0/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.8.0/css/alertify.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.8.0/css/themes/default.min.css"/>

</head>

<body>


<button class="btn-test">Click Me</button>


</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```